# bash: "No such file or directory" when trying to automate a mysqldump

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up a simple script to backup a mysql database:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Dumps mydatabase to ~/Developer/mydatabase_dumps/
#

dumpfile="~/Developer/mydatabase_dumps/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").sql"
echo "Dumping mydatabase to $dumpfile ..."
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > "$dumpfile"
echo "Dump completed."
```

That shouldn't be too complicated, but I always get "No such file or directory":

```
user$: pwd
/home/myname/Developer/bash_scripts
user$: ls -l
-rwxrw-r-- 1 myname myname 268 Apr 27 15:15 dbdump   # name of the script
user$: dbdump   # ./dbdump or sh dbdump produce the same result
Dumping mydatabase to ~/Developer/mydatabase_dumps/2017-04-27-15-22-06.sql ...
/home/myname/Developer/bash_scripts/dbdump: line 8: ~/Developer/mydatabase_dumps/2017-04-27-15-22-06.sql: No such file or directory
Dump completed.
```

The script was written on Ubuntu, so it shouldn't be a problem with Windows line endings. Changing the permissions to 777 didn't work either. I've run a bit out of ideas here, would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Change ~ to /home/user/

Comment: @MichaelO. Thanks, that did it!

Comment: Or use `$HOME` instead of `~`. Some old shells do not support `~`.